# Does @readonly always have limit of 1mil rows in VF context

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

Does the @readonly annotation on a VF controller method always limit to 1mil rows?  Or does that limit only apply when the annotation is on the page itself?  Docs are ambiguous: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_readonly_context.htm

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it always caps at 1 million when called from Visualforce. But one way to work around this is to prepare summary tables from Apex that are not called from Visualforce and then have the VF page reference these summary data after processing is complete.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Salesforce has updated the documentation since 10 years ago to make it clearer that the 1M limit applies to both.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.242.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_ReadOnly.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_readonly_context_pagelevel.htm

The purpose of the page-level readOnly="true" is both:

1. "...limit relaxed to allow querying up to 1,000,000 rows."
2. "...increases the maximum number of items in a collection that can be iterated over using components such as apex:dataTable, apex:dataList, and apex:repeat. This limit increased from 1,000 items to 10,000."